# The size of canonical embedding?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $n$ be an integer of the form $n=2^k$ for some $k\ge 2$.
Let $K$ be a number field $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^n+ 1\rangle$ and $\mathcal O_K$ be the ring of integers of $K$.
For an integer $q$, we define a quotient ring $R = \mathcal O_K / q \mathcal O_K \cong (\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})[x]/\langle x^n+ 1\rangle$.

Let $a$ be a uniformly sampled element from $R$.
Then, for $2n$-th root of unity $\zeta$, I heuristically guess that it holds that $|a(\zeta)| \in [q/(2\sqrt{n}),q\sqrt{n}/2]$ with high probability.
However, I cannot determine whether this conjecture is true or not and I do now know how to prove this even if the statement is true.

How can I prove that $|a(\zeta)| \in [q/(2\sqrt{n}),q\sqrt{n}/2]$ with some probability? Is there any reference?

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim since n is a power of two, the polynomial is irreducible. Indeed, the first equation $x^n+1 \neq (x^{n/2}+1)(x^{n/2}-1)$. Actually, it is $x^n-1$.

Comment: You're right, I had a brain fart. I'll delete my comment in a moment.

Comment: What do you mean by $|a(\xi)|$? It sounds like you want to treat $a$ as a polynomial with integer coefficients but $a$ is, by definition, a polynomial with $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients.

Comment: For $n > 2$, $q\Bbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is dense in $\Bbb{C}$, so I can't only think to the $\min $ of the Minkowski norms of the elements of $a+q\Bbb{Z}[\zeta]$